# Rewrite Magento2 Not working

Tags: magento2

Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox I want to rewrite this file and I have done this code but not working

> Custom\Outofstock\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" type="Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox" />
```

> Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox.php

```
    <?php
     namespace Ec\Outofstock\Pricing\Render;

     use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
     use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

    class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
    {
        protected function _toHtml()
       {
            $result = parent::_toHtml();

            if(!$result) {
                $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
                try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }

            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }

            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for **Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox** file also.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see by the first review, that you have used

```
namespace Ec\Outofstock\Pricing\Render;
```

instead of

```
namespace Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render;
```

Please check and change it and let me know if still, you have the issue same.

Comment: i have change that but not working

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for your **FinalPriceBox.php** file:

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Outofstock\Pricing\Render;

use Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Price\MsrpPrice;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\PriceBox as BasePriceBox;

class FinalPriceBox extends \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $result = parent::_toHtml();

        if(!$result) {
            $result = BasePriceBox::_toHtml();
            try {
                /** @var MsrpPrice $msrpPriceType */
                $msrpPriceType = $this->getSaleableItem()->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('msrp_price');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                $this->_logger->critical($e);
                return $this->wrapResult($result);
            }

            //Renders MSRP in case it is enabled
            $product = $this->getSaleableItem();
            if ($msrpPriceType->canApplyMsrp($product) && $msrpPriceType->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product)) {
                /** @var BasePriceBox $msrpBlock */
                $msrpBlock = $this->rendererPool->createPriceRender(
                    MsrpPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                    $this->getSaleableItem(),
                    [
                        'real_price_html' => $result,
                        'zone' => $this->getZone(),
                    ]
                );
                $result = $msrpBlock->toHtml();
            }

            return $this->wrapResult($result);
        }

    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i already change Custom to Ec

Comment: On which file? Everywhere?

Comment: yes everywhere event if i put exit here my fornt page distrub

Comment: Can you try to return static value and check if its showing on frontend? Otherwise you need to use Plugin for that.

Comment: already done that both

Comment: can you give me the link of Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your registration.php module name is similar like in module.xml(No typo there)

And check after removing generated folder

> rm -rf generated/*